# Probability distribution,mean and variance

Tags: probability

A team of 3 is to be chosen from 4 girls and 6 boys. If X is the number of girls in the team,
find the probability distribution of X ,its mean and variance

Comment: What have you tried?  I assume, though you don't say, that the $3$ are to be chosen uniformly at random from the sample...so, what is the probability that $X=0$?  $X=1$? and so on.

Comment: I have tried getting the values of x and found out they are 2,1,and 0.but i need help in finding their probabilities

Answer (score 1):

It is:
$$P(0)=P(B\cap B\cap B)=\frac{6}{10}\cdot \frac{5}{9}\cdot \frac{4}{8}=\frac16.$$
$$P(1)=P(G\cap B\cap B)+P(B\cap G\cap B)+P(B\cap B\cap G)=3\cdot \frac{4}{10}\cdot \frac{6}{9}\cdot \frac{5}{8}=\frac12.$$
$$P(2)=P(G\cap G\cap B)+P(G\cap B\cap G)+P(B\cap G\cap G)=3\cdot \frac{4}{10}\cdot \frac{3}{9}\cdot \frac{6}{8}=\frac{3}{10}.$$
$$P(3)=P(G\cap G\cap G)=\frac{4}{10}\cdot \frac{3}{9}\cdot \frac{2}{8}=\frac{1}{30}.$$

Comment: Please explain for me further.how are you getting those values at P(0)

Comment: $X=0$ implies no girls, but only boys. $P(0)$ implies probability of selecting $3$ boys in a row. Probability of selecting the first boy: $P(B)=\frac{6}{10}$. Probability of selecting the first two boys: $P(B\cap B)=\frac{6}{10}\cdot \frac{5}{9}$. And probability of selecting the first three boys is given above.

Comment: where is the value 3 coming from at P(2) and P(3)

Comment: The three addends are equal (equally likely).

Comment: Can you kindly draw for me a tree diagram showing the probabilities?